# cannot download fragment-1.1.0.jar

Tags: flutter, android-studio

#### Problem

Starting a new *Flutter* project in *Android Studio*, I get this error when trying to run the app on emulator.[click to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgORt.png)

#### Fix

In *build.gradle* go to `repositories` and replace `google()` with

```
maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
}
```

Eventually,your gradle repository should look like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

#### Why this worked?

by changing this line of code we changed the repository that gradle would look for fragment 1.1.0
jar file in.
Apparently this jar file is missing from the default google repositories and this causes that error.

Comment: If you have a solution answer your own question.

Comment: thanks. I didn't know. next time!